# How to access to an json objet array in typescript view

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm working on a project which has front end app in Angular. After cast my response coming from back end API,I'am trying to display array data in table,if   condition come true here is my array of data  compte['ingroup'].

```
<ul class="nav nav-list " *ngFor=" let compte of  comptes">
   <label class="groupcompte" *ngIf="{{compte['ingroup']}}.lenght > 0" >                                                                
      {{compte['ingroup']| json}}
   </label>
</ul>
```

My question is about know how to get compte['ingroup'] lenght in my condition
 thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should be `*ngIf="compte['ingroup'].length > 0"`

Comment: You don't use `{{}}` in `ngIf` expressions!

Comment: My bad! Corrected it

Comment: sorry but I have try  what your suggest but  it's not working

Comment: In that case, can you please share a bit more? like your data structure of `comptes` and what exactly are you trying to show in your table?